# How to query RethinkDB NoSQL Database from iOS App?

Tags: ios, rethinkdb, nosql

I have a RethinkDB database with a table that contains information that I need in my iOS app. I've been told that I can use JSON and POST requests to submit/download data from the database, but am not sure how to go about doing so. Here's what I have so far:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@:%i", hostName, portNumber]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

Once the connection is opened, how do I go about querying the RethinkDB server? I want to be able to download a certain number of entries and use the built-in "limit" and sort functions. Thank you in advance.

Comment: your xcode doesn't "query" the db. it contacts a web service which does the querying on its behalf.

Comment: @MarcB No, Xcode is an IDE. It doesn't query anything. The running app (that may have been written using Xcode) does the querying.

Comment: @rmaddy: true 'nuff. either way, you don't talk to the db directly, you talk to a webservice intermediary

Comment: @KaiBanks You need to talk to the server folks and find out what API they provide.

Comment: @rmaddy, the API is provided by RethinkDB, which is essentially a noSQL database. I just need to figure out how to encapsulate Javascript/Python/Ruby or other query languages into my code - any ideas or helpful links?